# Python list to text file and back to a list

Tags: python, list, text

I have a list from split() that look like this:

```
row[0] = ['one', 'two', 'three']
row[1] = ['three', 'four', 'five']
```

I write it to a text file and it looks like this:

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
['three', 'four', 'five']
```

And now I want to make a list again from my text file that would look like this:

```
row[0] = ['one', 'two', 'three']
row[1] = ['three', 'four', 'five']
```

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: Why do you need `[` and `]` to be added to your text file?

Comment: `CSV` file? https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: `row[0] = 'one', 'two', 'three'` is not a valid Python construction. Re-think your target. (It is *valid* but it's not a list.)

Comment: I'm scraping a website table and importing it to a db, It got very complicated and messy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
text = "['one', 'two', 'three']"
text = text[2:-2]
text_list = text.split("', '")
```

Hacky but gets the job done.

Also please reconsider why you want the text file to look like

```
['one', 'two', 'three']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to serialize a list to disk for later use by a python program, I would suggest [pickleing](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html) the list. Why reinvent the wheel when Python has serialization built in?

```
import pickle

with open('outfile', 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(row, fp)
```

To read it back:

```
with open ('outfile', 'rb') as fp:
    row = pickle.load(fp)
```